# How to get Value from ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

My Java list looks like below:

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

City: Berlin, Document guid: 08c14773-db81-4c43-8b66-51e5d39a4b2d, Content: null
City: Amsterdam, Document guid: 28c14773-db81-4c43-8b66-51e5d39a4b2d, Content: null
City: Tokio, Document guid: 18c14773-db81-4c43-8b66-51e5d39a4b2d, Content: null
```

And I need get value from Content. Below code show all values, but how can I get string from **Content**?

```
 for (int i=0;i < al.size();i++){
   Log.i("Value of element "+i, String.valueOf(al.get(i)));
 }
```

Comment: can you please re formulate the information... what is **"City: Berlin, Document guid: 08c14773-db81-4c43-8b66-51e5d39a4b2d, Content: null"**, an object?, a json?...?

Comment: How does your object look like?

Comment: Then your list keeps Content object ??

Comment: Yes, but I can't find a definition of it. Maybe some substring or matches?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
String[] splitString = al.get(0).split(": ");
System.out.println(splitString[splitString.length - 1]);
```

That being said you should probably create an `Object` to store all this data then put the `Object` in the `ArrayList`...

Comment: @user5523912 of creating a `Class`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i=0;i < al.size();i++){
   String currentValue = al.get(i);
   String[] partsOfCurrentValue = currentValue.split(",");

   for (String part : partsOfCurrentValue) {
        If (part.trim().startsWith("Content")) {
            String[] partsOfContent = part.split(":");
            String valueOfContent = partsOfContent[1];
            Log.i("Value of element "+i, valueOfContent);
            break;
        }
   }

 }
```

Comment: In your example   If (part.startsWith("Content")) { loop never go into

Comment: Could be due to there is a " " (empty space) before the part " Content:...". Please see the edited code above.

Answer (score 0):

Define your own class for this:

```
public class INfo {

    private String city;
     private String uuid;
     private String content;
     /**
      * @param city
      * @param uuid
      * @param content
      */
     public INfo(String city, String uuid, String content) {
         this.city = city;
         this.uuid = uuid;
         this.content = content;
     }

    /**
     * @return the city
     */
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    /**
     * @param city the city to set
     */
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    /**
     * @return the uuid
     */
    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    /**
     * @param uuid the uuid to set
     */
    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    /**
     * @return the content
     */
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    /**
     * @param content the content to set
     */
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

then define your list

```
 List<INfo> infList = new ArrayList<INfo>();
```

and finally every elemet of the List is actually an instance of the Info class, so you can get the attributes of the object by calling the getter... like:

```
System.out.println(infList.get(0).getCity());
```